# pd.read_excel error when reading from a directory

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am a Python beginner.

I was trying to read some excel files (.xlsx) from one folder using pd.read_excel.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def get_data(data_path):
    print(f"Reading data from {data_path}")
    data = pd.read_excel(data_path, engine='openpyxl')
    num_rows, num_columns = data.shape
    print("Original data:")
    print(data.head(100))  # 输出数据框的前几行
    print(f"Number of rows:{num_rows}")
    print(f"Number of columns:{num_columns}")
    print("Number of rows in data:", len(data))
    return data

data_path = r'E:\SVN_Pengfei\5.2020年工作\BaiduNetdiskWorkspace\1.ATM项目\4.技术文档\高速数据资料\北五环数据\雷达数据'
predict_values_name = ' Speed Value'
data=get_data(data_path)
```

but it always shows error:

```
 Reading data from E:\SVN_Pengfei\5.2020年工作\BaiduNetdiskWorkspace\1.ATM项目\4.技术文档\高速数据资料\北五环数据\雷达数据
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/SVN_Pengfei/5.2020年工作/BaiduNetdiskWorkspace/1.ATM项目/2.相关软件/模型、代码及说明文档/LSTM预测流量/test1.py", line 19, in <module>
    data=get_data(data_path)
  File "e:/SVN_Pengfei/5.2020年工作/BaiduNetdiskWorkspace/1.ATM项目/2.相关软件/模型、代码及说明文档/LSTM预测流量/test1.py", line 8, in get_data
    data = pd.read_excel(data_path, engine='openpyxl')
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 480, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 492, in load_workbook
    filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 345, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links, rich_text)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 93, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

I can change the data_path to one specific file, like
data_path = r'E:\SVN_Pengfei\5.2020年工作\BaiduNetdiskWorkspace\1.ATM项目\4.技术文档\高速数据资料\北五环数据\雷达数据\abcde.xlsx'

it works well, but I don't want do that, I want it read the folder, I will have another module to process multiple files.

pandas version:1.1.5
python version:3.7.0

Comment: I don't know whether pd.read_excel allowed to read from a directory or not. so I just edit my code to :data_path = os.getcwd()
exl_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path,"*.xlsx")), and now it can read all .xlsx in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `engine='openpyxl'` for `xlrd` engine for read `.xls` files:

```
data = pd.read_excel(data_path)
```

Or is possible set it explicitly:

```
data = pd.read_excel(data_path, engine='xlrd')
```